# woocommerce_get_price filter hook not working for product variation price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I have modified my product price based on a user who is logged in with a "reseller" role. This works for my default products, but not for my product variation products.

So my product price for a 50ml variation of the product is 9.20. A "reseller" should pay 6.16 (9.20 * 0.67). The output of my variation product is still 9.20..

**Filter hook:**

```
function pr_reseller_price( $price, $product ) {

   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
      return $price;

   // Function which checks if logged in user is reseller
   if ( pr_has_role( 'reseller' ) ) {
      $price = $price * 0.67;
   }
   return $price;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'pr_reseller_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_regular_price', 'pr_reseller_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sale_price', 'pr_reseller_price', 10, 2 );
```

**Product vs Product variation**

```
// Product
$product_id = 69;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
echo $product->get_price(); // Returns 6.16 (9.20 * 0.67)

// Product variation
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variations[0]['variation_id'] );
echo $variation->get_price(); // Returns 9.20
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add the filter hook for product variation as well.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'pr_reseller_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'pr_reseller_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'pr_reseller_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'pr_reseller_price', 10, 2 );
```